# How to create rotation on perspective camera on Three.js?

Tags: three.js, 3d, perspectivecamera

I have build a little 3D-TileMap in `Three.js`.

Currently, i have problems with my `PerspectiveCamera`. I wan't to add some camera handling like `Map rotating` or `zooming`. The zooming always works, here i'm only use the `field of view` and `mousewheel`.

But how i can implement a rotating of my map? When i'm using the coordinates of `camera` to modify **x**, **y** or **z**, i've misunderstand the calculation.

Here is my current work:

```js
function Input(renderer, camera) {
    var press = false
    var sensitivity = 0.2

    renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
     if(!press){ return }

     camera.position.x += event.movementX * sensitivity
     camera.position.y += event.movementY * sensitivity 
     camera.position.z += event.movementY * sensitivity / 10
    })    

    renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', () => { press = true })
    renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', () => { press = false })
    renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => { press = false })

    renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousewheel', event => {
     // Add MIN/MAX LIMITS
     const ratio = camera.position.y / camera.position.z
     camera.position.y -= (event.wheelDelta * sensitivity * ratio)
     camera.position.z -= (event.wheelDelta * sensitivity)
     camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    })
   }
   var controls;
   const Type = 'WebGL'; // WebGL or Canvas
   var _width, _height, CUBE_SIZE, GRID, TOTAL_CUBES, WALL_SIZE, HALF_WALL_SIZE,
    MAIN_COLOR, SECONDARY_COLOR, cubes, renderer, camera, scene, group
   var clock = new THREE.Clock();
   clock.start();
   var FOV = 45;
   _width = window.innerWidth
   _height = window.innerHeight

   CUBE_SIZE = 80 /* width, height */
   GRID = 12 /* cols, rows */
   TOTAL_CUBES = (GRID * GRID)
   WALL_SIZE = (GRID * CUBE_SIZE)
   HALF_WALL_SIZE = (WALL_SIZE / 2)
   MAIN_COLOR = 0xFFFFFF
   SECONDARY_COLOR = 0x222222
   cubes = []
   var directions = [];
   var normalized = [];
   
   switch(Type) {
    case 'WebGL':
     renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
    break;
    case 'Canvas':
     renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({antialias: true})    
    break;
   }
   
   camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, (_width / _height), 0.1, 10000)
   scene = new THREE.Scene()
   group = new THREE.Object3D()

   /* -- -- */
   setupCamera(0, 0, 800)
   setupBox(group)
   setupFloor(group)
   setupCubes(group)
   setupLights(group)
   group.position.y = 10
   group.rotation.set(-60 * (Math.PI/180), 0, -45 * (Math.PI/180))
   scene.add(group)
   setupRenderer(document.body)
   window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false)
   new Input(renderer, camera);
   /* -- -- */
   function resizeHandler() {
    _width = window.innerWidth
    _height = window.innerHeight
    renderer.setSize(_width, _height)
    camera.aspect = _width / _height
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
   }

   /* -- CAMERA -- */
   function setupCamera(x, y, z) {
    camera.position.set(x, y, z)
    scene.add(camera)
   }

   /* -- BOX -- */
   function setupBox(parent) {
    var i, boxesArray, geometry, material

    boxesArray = []
    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(WALL_SIZE, WALL_SIZE, 0.05)
    geometry.faces[8].color.setHex(SECONDARY_COLOR)
    geometry.faces[9].color.setHex(SECONDARY_COLOR)
    geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
     color : MAIN_COLOR,
     vertexColors : THREE.FaceColors,
     overdraw: 0.5
    })

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     boxesArray.push(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material))
    }

    // back
    boxesArray[0].position.set(0, HALF_WALL_SIZE, -HALF_WALL_SIZE)
    boxesArray[0].rotation.x = 90 * (Math.PI/180)

    // right
    boxesArray[1].position.set(HALF_WALL_SIZE, 0, -HALF_WALL_SIZE)
    boxesArray[1].rotation.y = -90 * (Math.PI/180)

    // front
    boxesArray[2].position.set(0, -HALF_WALL_SIZE, -HALF_WALL_SIZE)
    boxesArray[2].rotation.x = -90 * (Math.PI/180)

    // left
    boxesArray[3].position.set(-HALF_WALL_SIZE, 0, -HALF_WALL_SIZE)
    boxesArray[3].rotation.y = 90 * (Math.PI/180)

    // bottom
    boxesArray[4].position.set(0, 0, -WALL_SIZE)

    boxesArray.forEach(function(box) {
     box.renderOrder = 1;
     parent.add(box)
    
    });
    
   }

   /* -- FLOOR -- */
   function setupFloor(parent) {
    var i, tilesArray, geometry, material

    tilesArray = []
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(WALL_SIZE, WALL_SIZE)
    material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
     color : MAIN_COLOR,
     overdraw: 1
    })

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
     tilesArray.push(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material))
    }

    tilesArray[0].position.set(-WALL_SIZE, WALL_SIZE, 0)
    tilesArray[1].position.set(0, WALL_SIZE, 0)
    tilesArray[2].position.set(WALL_SIZE, WALL_SIZE, 0)
    tilesArray[3].position.set(-WALL_SIZE, 0, 0)
    tilesArray[4].position.set(WALL_SIZE, 0, 0)
    tilesArray[5].position.set(-WALL_SIZE, -WALL_SIZE, 0)
    tilesArray[6].position.set(0, -WALL_SIZE, 0)
    tilesArray[7].position.set(WALL_SIZE, -WALL_SIZE, 0)

    tilesArray.forEach(function(tile) {
     tile.receiveShadow = true
     tile.renderOrder = 4;
     parent.add(tile)
    })
   }

   /* -- CUBES --*/
   function setupCubes(parent) {
   
    var i, geometry, material, x, y, row, col

    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(CUBE_SIZE, CUBE_SIZE, 0.05)
    
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
     map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://ak.game-socket.de/assets/grass.png'),
     normalMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://ak.game-socket.de/assets/paper_low_nmap.png'),
     overdraw: 1,
     depthTest: true,
     depthWrite: true
    } );
   
   
    x = 0
    y = 0
    row = 0
    col = 0

    for (i = 0; i < TOTAL_CUBES; i++) {
     cubes.push(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material))

     if ((i % GRID) === 0) {
      col = 1
      row++
     } else col++

     x = -(((GRID * CUBE_SIZE) / 2) - ((CUBE_SIZE) * col) + (CUBE_SIZE/2))
     y = -(((GRID * CUBE_SIZE) / 2) - ((CUBE_SIZE) * row) + (CUBE_SIZE/2))

     cubes[i].position.set(x, y, 0)
    }

    cubes.forEach(function(cube, index) {
     if(index % 2 == 0) {
      directions[index] = -1;
      normalized[index] = false;
     } else {
      directions[index] = 1;
      normalized[index] = true;
     }
     
     cube.castShadow = true
     cube.receiveShadow = true
     cube.rotation.x = 0;
     cube.renderOrder = 3;
     cube.doubleSide = true;
     parent.add(cube)
    })
   }

   /* -- LIGHTS -- */
   function setupLights(parent) {
    var light, soft_light
    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(MAIN_COLOR, 1.25)
    soft_light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(MAIN_COLOR, 1.5)
    light.position.set(-WALL_SIZE, -WALL_SIZE, CUBE_SIZE * GRID)
    light.castShadow = true
    soft_light.position.set(WALL_SIZE, WALL_SIZE, CUBE_SIZE * GRID)
    parent.add(light).add(soft_light)
   }

   /* -- RENDERER -- */
   function setupRenderer(parent) {
    renderer.setSize(_width, _height)
    renderer.setClearColor(MAIN_COLOR, 1.0);
    parent.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
   }

   var speed = 0.003;
   var reach = 40;
   
   function render() {
    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    
    cubes.forEach(function(cube, index) {
     cube.castShadow = true
     cube.receiveShadow = true
     
     if(directions[index] >= 1) {
      ++directions[index];
      
      if(directions[index] >= reach) {
       directions[index] = -1
      }
      
      cube.rotation.x += speed;
     } else if(directions[index] <= -1) {
      --directions[index];
      
      if(directions[index] <= -reach) {
       directions[index] = 1
      }
      
      cube.rotation.x -= speed;
     }
    });
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
   }

   render();
```

```css
html, body, canvas {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/shaders/ParallaxShader.js"></script>
```

By option, i don't want, that the rotating/zooming reach the end of the map - The user is not able to look under the map, as example.

Comment: I recommend you to use [OrbitControls](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls)

Comment: I've tried `OrbitControls`, but all available settings do not make the view as I would like it.